# How can I trace where my application would call a doGet() or doPost method?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to debug my application to find out why it isn't accessing a class it's supposed to, and I've found that there's a doGet() method that the application needs to call, but that it never reaches.

I want to know what the app is doing *before* it would reach that point, but according to answers in  [How doGet() or doPost method invokes service() method internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21973543/how-doget-or-dopost-method-invokes-service-method-internally) and [doGet or doPost method invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27292471/doget-or-dopost-method-invocation), there isn't any direct call to these methods - it's just the servlet container calling those methods.

So how can I, in simple terms, find out where the application would call my doGet method?  (If it helps at all, this is a legacy app using Struts 1.2, and the method's parameters are (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)).

I've placed a logger message at the first line of the method, so I know it isn't ever reaching the method itself.  But I don't know what to look at next to try and debug our application problems.

Comment: That's gonna send you to the .class of the servlet package x)

Comment: @Nathan while probably true, this is also terribly unhelpful. :( I'm woefully unfamiliar with this process, and not even sure where I'd find the .class of the servlet package, let alone how to debug it or figure out why I'm being sent there.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem? If yes you could post what you did as an answer for the next one. Also, what I meant by _"sending you to the .class of the servlet package"_ was that you were gonna end up on the compiled code of the servlet API, which you can't really debug (unless you're ready to suffer).

Comment: @Nathan Sort of, but not really.  We determined that there's a server-side issue with our application's interaction with our server's refresh client.  For now, since this client hasn't been migrated to our Production environment, this is fine.  But we will still need to eventually resolve this issue.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to your question, but shouldn't you debug the code **calling** the doGet method to check where the problem lies? For example, are you doing a `request.forward` or a redirection to your url endpoint? If yes, can you post this part of your code?